# subprocess not working when running inside pycharm

Tags: python, git, pycharm, subprocess

Well I try to make a python script download some git data using a shell command. However I expect the git command to "query" for user login, and report the status to the shell used to call python. I tried doing this using pipe.

```
subprocess.run('git clone SERVER ./build',
               shell=True)
```

However I don't see anything happening, and the python process just waits without asking for input.

**when I run it in a terminal directly using python main.py it does work**, it is just that when running through the pycharm IDE the input and out is eaten.
Just for more clarification: when I run it through the launcher of pycharm I do notice that the process "never ends" untill I kill it, raising `KeyboardInterrupt`. So it is waiting "somewhere" for the user input, it's just that the input isn't shown in the pycharm console.

How should I do this? If I don't add `shell=True` subprocess complains that the `git` command is not an existing file/directory.

Comment: Why `pip` is mentioned in the title?

Comment: @phd no idea, freud? - removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under run settings there's a configuration flag that needs to be set for this to work:

in *Configuration tab*, under *Execution*, tick **emulate terminal output in console**.

In my case I had to restart pycharm for this to take effect when updating old configurations (it worked directly when adding it to a new run configuration).

Answer (score -2):

I recommend you use `subprocess.call` instead.

And when running shell commands in an IDE, you may need to specify the full path to the executable.

```py
git_exec = '/usr/local/bin/git'

returncode = subprocess.call('{0} clone SERVER ./build'.format(git_exec), 
                             shell=True)
if returncode != 0:
    # Code wasn't executed successfully
    # Do something
    pass
```

Comment: This is definitely a step in the wrong direction. `subprocess.run()` does everything `subprocess.call()` does, and then some. There's nothing wrong with using the legacy function but there should be no reason to switch back if you use its modern replacement.