# Sub-process stdout using file object not working when using PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, subprocess

I have a simple snippet of Python program which correctly works using IDLE or Windows's CMD. But I am not able to make it work using PyCharm.
The goal is to run `nc.exe` (to get logs from a device under test) using `subprocess.Popen` and to redirect the sub-process `stdout` to a log file. Below is the python code

```py
import subprocess

nc_ex = r"C:\Users\lambda\Desktop\Tool\nc.exe"
ipaddr = "192.168.51.202"
port = "3001"
log_file = open("test_file.bin", "wb")
p = subprocess.Popen([nc_ex, ipaddr, port], stdout=log_file)
```

Using IDLE or CMD, the log file is correctly growing with logs received. Using PyCharm the log file remains empty. I tried to deal with `subprocess.Popen` arguments value (creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE), look for Pycharm configuration, follow this topic [subprocess not working when running inside pycharm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813102/subprocess-not-working-when-running-inside-pycharm) , but I can't figure it out. Does anyone has a solution to this strange behavior?

Comment: have you tried to `p.wait()` until the process has completed?

Comment: are you running with an integrated terminal in pycharm ?

Comment: have you verified whether the nc.exe is running in the task manager after running your code from pycharm ?

Comment: @novice: nc process is well running in the task manager until I call p.terminate().

Comment: @D.L: I am running the program in the pycharm python console but using "Run" does the same.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: the process in running in background until p.terminate() is called.